# how to implement vh and vw font-size unit for responsive font for older android browsers?

Tags: android, css, font-size, android-browser, viewport-units

It seems that older browsers of android doesn't support vh and vw font-size unit in css. Is there any way to use vw and vh or any other way to make fonts responsive in older browsers of android? I have lots of text with different font sizes and I don't want to use media query.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using jquery.There are 3 steps to make fonts responsive.

1. Adjust you fonts for a fixed with.For example 800px.
2. Use a class name in any dom element where you want to make the font
   responsive.For example `class="rf"` (responsive font).
3. Use the jquery code bellow to make the fonts responsive.

html code..

```
<div class="rf">this is sample text</div>
```

jquery code..

```
$(function(){

  var element = $('.rf');
    element.each(function (i) {
        fonts = $(this).css('font-size');
        fonts = fonts.replace("px","");
        windowWidth = $(window).width();
        fontSize = fonts*windowWidth/800;
        $(this).css('font-size',fontSize);
    });

})
```

change the code according to your class name "rf" and the with that you have used to adjust your font size "800".

Comment: well that was tricky. this will work, but I think there is some performance issue because this will load everything of the page than it will loop through all the class than the font will change. and if I want it in device orientation change I have to do that on orientation change. is there any faster way?

Comment: Set a font size for the body element (default is 16px), set all other font sizes as percentages (e.g. 24px becomes 150%), then have a script check the width of the screen and adjust the body font size; all other font sizes will adjust automatically.  
See my question and the workaround I posted about a similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280345/viewport-unit-font-size-and-zooming-bug-which-browsers-are-affected